# failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c unzip awscliv2.zip" did not complete successfully: exit code: 9

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to make a request for zip from aws and then unzip the file, I tried changing the path inside docker, I tried adding apt install unzip. But I can't unzip the file to run it inside the container, would you have a solution for that? Because soon after I'm going to use the boto3 library and I need this file.

dockerfile:

```bash
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-wheel gcc g++ make python3-opencv curl wget unzip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app


COPY ./aws/xxx.xxx.csv /app/xxx.xxx.csv


RUN wget -o awscliv2.zip https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install
RUN aws configure import --csv file:///xxx.xxx.csv
RUN aws configure set region us-east-1
RUN pip3 install cython==0.29.24
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 uninstall pymoo -y && pip3 install pymoo==0.4.2.2 --compile
```

docker compose:

```bash
version: '3.0'

services:
    app:
        build: .
        env_file:
            - .env
        restart: always
        entrypoint: ['/bin/sh', '-c']
        command:
            - |
                alembic upgrade head
                uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port ${PORT} app:app
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app/app

        ports:
            - '127.0.0.1:${PORT}:${PORT}'
```

erro output:

```bash
[+] Building 0.8s (16/34)                                                                                                                                                    
 => [service-app internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 50B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [service-app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 906B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [service-app internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04                                                                                          0.5s
 => [service-worker internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 906B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [service-worker internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 50B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [service-app  1/15] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:20.04@sha256:24a0df437301598d1a4b62ddf59fa0ed2969150d70d748c84225e6501e9c36b9                                  0.0s
 => [service-worker internal] load build context                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 172B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [service-app internal] load build context                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 172B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [service-worker  2/15] RUN apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-dev python3-pip python3-wheel gcc g++ mak  0.0s
 => CACHED [service-worker  3/15] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [service-worker  4/15] COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [service-worker  5/15] COPY setup.cfg /app/setup.cfg                                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [service-worker  6/15] COPY alembic.ini /app/alembic.ini                                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [service-worker  7/15] COPY ./aws/xxx.xxx.csv /app/xxx.xxx.csv                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [service-worker  8/15] RUN wget -o awscliv2.zip https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [service-worker  9/15] RUN unzip awscliv2.zip                                                                                                              0.4s
------
 > [service-worker  9/15] RUN unzip awscliv2.zip:
#0 0.349 Archive:  awscliv2.zip
#0 0.349   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
#0 0.349   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
#0 0.349   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
#0 0.349   the last disk(s) of this archive.
#0 0.349 unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of awscliv2.zip or
#0 0.349         awscliv2.zip.zip, and cannot find awscliv2.zip.ZIP, period.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c unzip awscliv2.zip" did not complete successfully: exit code: 9
```

My expectation is to be able to run the next commands after unzipping this file

Comment: Try `docker compose build --no-cache` (or `docker-compose` if you're using that version)

Comment: `wget -o awscliv2.zip https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip` will create a zip file called `awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip` and a log file called `awscliv2.zip`.  You probably meant `wget -O awscliv2.zip https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip` (note the capital "O")

Comment: @AnonCoward It was this option "-O", operation completed successfully. Thanks.